# How to take average of all variables (seperately) based on indicator variable in SAS

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, average

I have a dataset containing say 100 variables and I want to take the average of all variables seperately based on an indicator variable indicating which values to take the average over. So I have the following:

```
Id   Var1    Var2     Var3  Take_Avg
1    …        …        …        1
2    …        …        …        2
3    …        …        …        3
4    …        …        …        9999
5    …        …        …        9999
6    …        …        …        9999
7    …        …        …        7
8    …        …        …        8
9    …        …        …        99999
10   …        …        …        99999
11   …        …        …        99999
12   …        …        …        99999
13   …        …        …        99999
14   …        …        …        14
15   …        …        …        15
```

So for id1, I just need the values of Var1, 2 and 3 (as the average will yield the same value I already have). For id 4 until 6, I need the average values of Var1, 2 and 3 seperately.

I tried creating this and taking the average of all variables in a `Group By` statement, but I do not know how. Is there a way to do this?

My desired results look like this:

```
Id   avg(Var1)      avg(Var2)     avg(Var3) 
1      …             …              …       
2      …             …              …      
3      …             …              …       
4      avg(id 4-6)   avg(id 4-6)    avg(id 4-6)
7      …             …              …      
8      …             …              …       
9      avg(id 9-13)  avg(id 9-13)   avg(id 9-13)
14     …             …              …       
15     …             …              …
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what your desired result looks like?

Comment: Please see changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with SAS you can use the procedure **proc means**, this procedure It's mainly used to calculate descriptive statistics such as mean, median, count, sum etc.

in  your case the code it is similar to:

```
Proc Means data = your_data_set MEAN;
 Class ID;
 Var var1 - var3;
 Output out = your_output_data_set mean= /autoname;
Run;
```

---

**class** is similar to group by.

---

**var** is similar to variables of analysis.

---

**output out** is the option for save to information in some dataset.

link of Detailed Explanation
[enter link description here](https://www.listendata.com/2015/01/sas-detailed-explanation-of-proc-means.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just asking for something like this:

```
select take_avg
     , min(id) as new_id 
     , mean(var1) as mean_var1
     , mean(var2) as mean_var2
     , mean(var3) as mean_var3
from have
group by take_avg
;
```